# The class i m adding to my element is getting added but upon removal is not getting removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Okay so my HTML for the navbar is here(I m using boostrap Nav)

```
<header>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="MyNav">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data- toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse" aria-expanded="false">
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#featured"><h1>Wisdom <span class="subhead">Pet Medicine</span></h1></a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse">
      <ul  class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="collapse">
          <li class="active"><a href="#featured">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#mission">Mission</a></li>
          <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#staff">Staff</a></li>
          <li><a href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>      
  </div>    
 </nav>
</header>
```

The javascript(JQuery) code is here,

```
$('.navbar-fixed-top').on('activate.bs.scrollspy',function(){    
    var current= $(this).find('#MyNav li .active a').attr('href');
    if(current !== '#featured'){
        $('header nav').addClass('inbody');
    }
    else{
        $('header nav').removeClass('inbody');
    }    
});
```

Now, the problem is that, whenever i scroll down to a section, the ACTIVE class changes to a different `li` tag and so the `inbody` class gets attached to the `<nav>` element, following the `IFCondition`. But when i scroll back up the `inbody` class is not getting removed as per the ELSE condition. Need help.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra space in selector for `li.active`

Change:

```
var current= $(this).find('#MyNav li .active a').attr('href');
                                    ^^ // extra space
```

To

```
var current= $(this).find('#MyNav li.active a').attr('href');
```

Your version looks for an active class inside the `<li>` not an `<li>` that has that class

Comment: Got the answer. I had to remove the #MyNav id from the find method, and it worked. I m still puzzled, why is so ?

Answer (score 0):

What @charlietfl said is correct. However a better solution might be to use the event target instead:

```
$('.navbar-fixed-top').on('activate.bs.scrollspy',function(ev){
    var current = $(ev.target).find('a').attr('href');
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There were two issues with this line of code:

```
var current= $(this).find('#MyNav li .active a').attr('href');
```

Your initial select $(this) will be your nav element. You then use .find() which searches for all **descendants** of the nav element. #MyNav isn't a descendant (its the same element) so the find function won't return anything.

The second issue is "li .active" which will look for elements with the active class that are a descendant of an li element. But you want li elements that have the class "active". In order to get that, don't include a space between them.

The line should look like this:

```
var current= $(this).find('li.active a').attr('href');
```